# Compile IL code at runtime using .NET 3.5 and C# from file

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, runtime, .net-assembly, ilasm

I would like to take a file that is an IL file, and at run time compile it back to an exe.

Right now I can use process.start to fire off the command line with parameters  (ilasm.exe) but I would like to automate this process from a C# service I will create.

Is there a way to do this with reflection and reflection.emit?

While this works:

```
string rawText = File.ReadAllText(string.Format("c:\\temp\\{0}.il", Utility.GetAppSetting("baseName")), Encoding.ASCII);

rawText = rawText.Replace("[--STRIP--]", guid);

File.Delete(string.Format("c:\\temp\\{0}.il", Utility.GetAppSetting("baseName")));

File.WriteAllText(string.Format("c:\\temp\\{0}.il", Utility.GetAppSetting("baseName")),rawText, Encoding.ASCII);

pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
pi.FileName = "\"" + ilasm + "\"";
pi.Arguments = string.Format("c:\\temp\\{0}.il", Utility.GetAppSetting("baseName"));

using(Process p = Process.Start(pi))
{
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

It is not ideal as I really would like this to be a streamlined process.

I have seen examples of creating the IL at runtime, then saving, but I need to use the IL I already have in file form and compile it back to an exe.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to use Reflection.Emit or dynamic methods depending on where does your IL come from. Is it generated?

Comment: The original IL will be generated from Ildasm.exe.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by a "streamlined process"? Is it not performing well enough for you? I know it feels slightly dirty to spawn a separate process, but it's the simplest way I can think of. With the appropriate permissions you should still be able to do this from a service.

You want something like CSharpCodeProvider but for IL; I don't know of any such class, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hello Jon,

Thanks for the reply.  It just feels like you say "clunky".  But if this is the only way to do it, then I guess I am stuck calling the command line.  

Another issue is that this is going to be a service, and might get a little heavy with usage at times.  I am not sure how calling a command line util will preform.

I just like having a more polished app.  Thanks.

Comment: @nitefrog: I understand the preference for a library over spawning a process - but if it works, I'd stick with that at the moment. You should probably work out your load and do a load test early on to see whether you'll be able to handle it.

Comment: Cecil is an assembly manipulation library. It reads and writes assemblies, not IL files.

Comment: @Jb Evain: That's what I suspected. I thought it was worth mentioning as a possible line of enquiry. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, many obfuscators, like [preemtive](http://www.preemtive.com) and [BitHelmet](http://www.bithelmet.com) uses ilasm.exe and Process. I think it is the best strategy.