# C# local application, to fetch variables from website in an open tab

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am trying very hard to find a way to allow exchage of information between an application running locally (made in C#) and an web application residing in an open tab of any web browser.

That is the typical user case:

- User login to the .NET MVC web application using their username and password. Once logged in they are assigned a guid and they are redirected to www.myapp.com/view/[guid] . Once there they are prompted to download and run the local application (or if it's already downloaded, to run it).
- Once they run the application, it should detect the [guid] and start posting information to the server www.myapp.com/postInfo/[guid].

Originally I thought about using ClickOnce and passing parameters to the clickonce launcher (?guid=[guid]). But clickonce is only supported in IE - chrome and firefox require a plugin which is a showstopper for me -

Then, I throught about using flash in the webapp to paste the guid in the clipboard, and have the local app constantly check the clipboard, but I don't think this is an elegenat solution, as it will erase the current contents of the clipboard.

Any thoughts on how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not package a file with the downloadable with the guid in that?

When the app starts; read the guid from that file.

or even better edit the app.config for that application prior to making available for download...

Another route would be altering the .exe prior to making available for download... [Modify Emdeded String in C# compiled exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742583/modify-emdeded-string-in-c-sharp-compiled-exe)

Comment: dave, thnx for your reply, that saved my day