# How to replace \r\n (literal) with \n using FART.exe

Tags: replace, grep, windows-console

I have an xml format file for bulk loading in SQL Server 2008. I need to replace the instance of `TERMINATOR="\r\n"` with `TERMINATOR="\n"`. I'm trying to use the command line utility `FART.exe`. No matter how I try, I cannot seem to get the utility to recognize the characters.

I have tried passing as combos of the find string and replace string:

```
\r\n \n
"\r\n" "\n"
""\r\n"" ""\n""
^\r^\n ^\n
TERMINATOR=""\r\n"" TERMINATOR=""\n""
TERMINATOR=""^\r^\n"" TERMINATOR=""^\n""
```

and many, many more combinations. Every article I look up about escaping `DOS` commands tells me something different and I've tried them all with no luck. The truly strange thing is that not only does using `\r\n \n` not do what I want it to do (replace the literals) but it does not replace the carriage return + line feed characters at the end of each line in the file.

The format file I need to edit.  I believe the line I've underlined in red is causing a problem:

[image]

The command window output from calling Jrepl.  It's obvious that the utility has a problem with the red-underlined line from the other screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To replace all `\r\n` literals with `\n`, simply use:

```
fart yourFile.xml \r\n \n
```

To only replace within larger string `TERMINATOR="\r\n"`, then use:

```
fart -C yourfile.xml TERMINATOR=\x22\\r\\n\x22 TERMINATOR=\x22\\n\x22
```

I prefer to use [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - It is much more powerful than FART in that it can use regular expressions, plus it has a number of additional advanced features. The only limitation relative to FART is it can only process one file at a time.

To replace all `\r\n` literals with `\n`:

```
jrepl \r\n \n /l /f yourFile.xml /o -
```

To be more specific using a literal search string with quote escaped as `\q` and backslash as `\\`:

```
jrepl "TERMINATOR=\q\\r\\n\q" "TERMINATOR=\q\\n\q" /x /l /f yourFile.xml /o -
```

or using a regular expression:

```
jrepl "(TERMINATOR=\q)\\r(?=\\n\q)" "$1" /x /f yourFile.xml /o -
```

Comment: Hi Dbenham.  Unfortunately the first thing I tried was "fart yourFile.xml \r\n \n" and it did not work.  I get the result "Replaced 0 occurence(s) in 0 file(s).  I only need to find and replace in one file at a time, so I think I will try your jrepl command line utility instead for now.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ognennyy - Hmmm. That is odd, because I tested with FART and it seemed to work for me. But good luck with JREPL

Comment: I've posted two screenshots above that I hope will help.  If I create just a text file with one line in it (Terminator="\r\n") then call jrepl \r\n \n /l /f "test.txt" /o "test_new.txt", it works correctly and replaces it with (Terminator="\n").  However, I seems like Jrepl doesn't like my xml file.  Check out my screenshot.  The line I hilighted in the xml file contains two links.  The other screenshot of the cmd window when I send output to stdout clearly demonstrates that it's having an issue there.  What do you think @dbenham ?  Will Jrepl not work with a full blown xml file?

Comment: Forgot to mention... I thought the issue was related to the links inside the <BCPFORMAT header item.  So I removed that line entirely, then reran Jrepl. It still did not work correctly and gave me strange output.  Then I tried saving the xml as a .txt file.  Still got the same issue.  So it's not just the link, it's something about the xml tags in there.  I also forgot to include a screenshot of the output of Jrepl on the full xml file.  I'll attach that now.  ...   ...  Not enough reputation.  The output file has two lines: the first is <?xml version="1.0"?>.  Second is a square shape

Comment: @Ognennyy - JREPL is designed to work with ANSI (extended ASCII) encoded files. My guess is your XML file is encoded as some form of Unicode (something other than UTF-8). That might also explain why FART did not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and quickest is fart binary method, for example:

```
fart.exe -C D:\sample.txt \x0d\x0a \x0a
```