# Reading/writing extended properties from an EXE

Tags: c#, install4j

We're creating setups with Install4j and require a way to statically save a readable property within the EXE.

The idea is that we save a JSON string to the Setup EXE containing the specific hardware pre-requisites information (min CPU, RAM etc). This JSON string would be read from the setup by our own installer management solution.

My question is 2 fold:

1. Can install4j add an extended, writable property detail to a setup?
2. In c# is there a way to read the new extended property?

Note:

- We would use a REST service to obtain the pre-requisites, but we have too many offline installs.
- We cannot have any additional files, it has to exist and be readable from an EXE using c#

Comment: maybe you can pass this JSON within a parameter to your setup? Dinamicly changing `.exe` is **always** a bad idea btw (your antivirus/group policy administrator will never forgive you for that).

Comment: Since its tagged with `C#` I assume it's a net assembly? So the question is "how to [read resources from net assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3314140/1997232) using Install4j"? Writing is harder, but should be also [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2742902/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in install4j to do that. It would also break the signature to write such a property.